# Using data given back with getJSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm currently working on a small project for university and I'm stuck.

It's a card game using jQuery and php (php is completely given). 
The php expects a GET with 3 parameters: dealer_cards, player_cards and card_for.
dealer_cards and player_cards is required to be a JSON formatted array. I did this with:

```
var dealer_cards = [];
var player_cards = [];
var dcJSON = JSON.stringify(dealer_cards);
var pcJSON = JSON.stringify(player_cards);
```

So I use

```
$.getJSON("routine.php", input, ...
```

and the server returns me everything I need, but now I need to safe the card the player received to the array.

How can I safe the JSON returned to the array? I tried tu use JSON.parse

JSON returned looks like this

```
Object {status: "okay", dealer_cards: Array(0), player_cards: Array(1), dealer_value: 0, player_value: 9…}
```

So I need to get into the player_cards Array and store the information.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the call back of `$.getJSON` call push on your array with the item you want to add, for example:

```
$.getJSON("routine.php", input, function(data) {
  player_cards.push(data.player_cards[0]);
});
```

Alternatively, if the response contains the entire array of player cards, you can simply overwrite your local copy, like this:

```
$.getJSON("routine.php", input, function(data) {
  player_cards = data.player_cards;
});
```

Comment: So do I have to "stringify" the array again when I use it again? 
I have a function called drawCard which runs when I click a button. I thought when I add the drawn card to the array and call the function again by clicking the button the new card should be in the array given as parameter with getJSON

Comment: That depends on what you do with it. If you're just passing it back in an Ajax request, then no, as jQuery will do it for you

Comment: I have the function drawCard which is triggered by a button click. The first time i click it the cards arrays should be empty. Then I get the response from the server with the card drawn. This card should be written in the array. The second time i click the button the array should contain the first card drawn.